# Modelling problem (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the below problem:

*The water level, y, in a tank is modelled by the differential equation*
$$\dot y(t) + y(t) = z(t)$$
*where z denotes the inflow. The inflow is a function of a valve position, which in turn is controlled by the electric control signal u. The relation between control signal and flow is given by the differential equation*
$$\ddot z(t) + \dot z(t) + z(t) = u(t)$$
*What differential equation relates the water level y to the control signal u?*

I am self-taught and did not do this kind of modelling problem before. I tried to google an example but I don't know which kind of problem is that exactly (modelling? state space form?). Can someone kindly give me some pointers on what to read to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z(t)=y(t)+\dot y(t)$.

$\dot z(t)=\dot y(t)+\ddot y(t)$.

$\ddot z(t)=\ddot y(t)+\dddot y(t)$.

By summing all this equations,

$$u(t)=z(t)+\dot z(t)+\ddot z(t)= y(t)+2\dot y(t)+2\ddot y(t)+\dddot y(t).$$
So tyhe EDO is
$$\dddot y(t)+2\ddot y(t)+2\dot y(t)+y(t)=u(t).$$

Comment: Thank you very much, but what is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: To look how $u(t)$ is obtained in terms of $z(t)$ and try to reproduce in terms of $y(t)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow so nice when somebody explains it kindly to you :)

Answer (score 1):

We have two linear differential operators $\mathcal{D}_1$ and $\mathcal{D}_2$ such that

$$
\cases{
\mathcal{D}_1[y] = z\\
\mathcal{D}_2[z] = u
}
$$

so the answer is

$$
\mathcal{D}_2[\mathcal{D}_1[y]] = u
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I chain D2 and D1?

Comment: $\mathcal{D}_1[\cdot]=\frac{d}{dt}[\cdot]+1[\cdot]$ and $\mathcal{D}_2[\cdot]=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}[\cdot]+\frac{d}{dt}[\cdot]+1[\cdot]$ and $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d}{dt}[\cdot]\right)$ etc.